# JSON and HTML without Array

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have my JSON file  and it is just an object not any array.

```
{"name":"Autogen Program","start":"2014-05-04","end":"2014-10-12","status":"Completed"}
```

I am trying to assign value from JSON into HTML but I am unable to do so

```
$(function() {

 $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(statusDataSet) {
    $.each(statusDataSet, function(i) {
    var color;
    switch(i.status) {
        case "In Progress":
            color = "yellow";
            break;
        case "Pending" : 
            color = "red";
            break;
        case "Completed" : 
            color = "green";
            break;
    }


    if(i.name=="Autogen Program") {
     $("#stat1").append(i.status).css('background-color', color);
    }

  });
     });
```

HTML Code :--

```
<tr>
    <form action="status1.asp">
        <td>
            <textarea readonly style="overflow:hidden" id="stat1" cols="12" rows="1" autofocus >   
            </textarea>
        </td>
   </form>
```

Can you please help me with same or suggest me where I am going wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: hope the issue is $.each(statusDataSet, function(index,i) instead $.each(statusDataSet, function(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to your `$.each` than you need to make sure the returned result is an array:

```
statusDataSet = (statusDataSet instanceof Array) ? statusDataSet : [statusDataSet];
```

And `$.each(function(i))` should be `$.each(function(i, item))` because your `i` is the index not the item (object)

Hope that helps

http://jsfiddle.net/bv1br9tL/

Comment: I dont have my JSON as array . I tried to use  for loop also instead of each but that is also not helping.

Comment: use the code line above between your `getJSON` and your `each` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p1zp9hrk/

Comment: $(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json',  function(statusDataSet) {
   
        for (var i = 0; i < statusDataSet.length; i++) {
    var color;
             switch(i.status) {
              case "In Progress":
                 color = "yellow";
                 break;
              case "Pending" : 
                 color = "red";
                 break;
              case "Completed" : 
                 color = "green";
                 break;
            }
              $("#stat1").append(statusDataSet[i].status);
            ;
             }
    });

Comment: @user2854333 that would loop through the Object, he needs to convert the object to an array before that would work...

Comment: Hi Gavin.. Thanks for your help. After making the changes also , I am unable to display the value in the Form.

Comment: How are you trying to display it? Can you update your question to include the form html and javascript you are now using, as @RoToRa and my answers work and should solve your problem, so there must be something else conflicting...

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON isn't a array, then you don't need the `$.each` loop. Just leave it out:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(statusDataSet) {
    var color;
    switch(statusDataSet.status) {
        case "In Progress":
            color = "yellow";
            break;
        case "Pending" : 
            color = "red";
            break;
        case "Completed" : 
            color = "green";
            break;
    }

    if(statusDataSet.name=="Autogen Program") {
      $("#stat1").append(statusDataSet.status).css('background-color', color);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't display the value in the form . The value still comes as blank in the form .

Comment: Does your AJAX call return the correct value? Have a look at the request in the network tab of your debugger.